# submit form data from a foreach loop

Tags: php

I have a foreach loop with a form inside for each result like so:

```
foreach($this->results() as $that) {
<form>
<input type="text" name="name[]">
<input type="text" name="this[]">
</form>
}
```

and so on. My question is how do I each forms data. I understand you can do something like the following:

```
$_POST['name'][0]; 
$_POST['name'][1];
```

etc, but is their a way to get this done without knowng how many forms their will be. I mean like foreach loop the $_POST data and get each form?

Many thanks

Comment: Add hidden element into the form which will track the number of forms. <?php $i=0;?> and inside for loop add <input type="hidden" value="$i++" name="formCount">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($_POST['name'] as $val) { /* do what you want, want you want with my value */ }
```

`$_POST['name']` is just an array. Use `count` or any array function you want on it then.

Comment: What about when it comes to the next $_POST you would have like foreach($_POST['this'] as $val2) {} but then how do you take the first value from name and first value from this so thats one form?

Comment: Using a `for` loop? `for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST['name']);$i++) { $_POST['name'][$i]... $_POST['this'][$i] }`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
foreach ($_POST['name'] as $val => $value) {}
```

assuming these rows are being  generated by a while loop, and the variable is named like this

```
  $val = $row['val'];
```

And then in your form you'd have something like this:

```
echo  '<input type="hidden" value="'.$val.'" name ="val[]" /><input type="text" name="name['.$val.'] />";
```

basically the name variable would be identified by the value itself being generated but also appended on a named variable, and then can be fed into your foreach.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($_POST['name'] as $key => $value) { 
   echo 'key: '.$key.' Value : '.$value;
}

--------------------------

output key: 0 Value : nameValue1 
key: 1 Value : nameValue2
```

$_POST['name'] is an array, if you get multiple value with key, just get with foreach value